# Index/Match in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, macros, match

I tried several ways, but I still have a problem in my code.

What I want to do (this example in **Q2 on Sheet4**):

```
=INDEX('Sheet8'!K:K,MATCH('Sheet4'!P2,'Sheet8'!A:A,0))
```

I'd like to do it for all rows with content in column **K on Sheet 4** so I'll probably need "For i = 1..."

What I tried:

```
For i = 1 To LastRowShort
row_mtch = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheet4.Cells("Q????").Value, Sheet8.Range("A1:A"), 0)

Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheet8.Range("K1:K" & LastRowShort), row_mtch)
Next i
```

Thanks a lot!
Andy

Entire Module:

```
Sub MissingBoth()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Dim MyRange, CopyRange As Range
 Dim LastRow As Long
 Dim LastRowSheet4 As Long
 Dim LastRowSheet8 As Long
 Set src4 = Sheet2
 Set dst4 = Sheet4
LastRow = src4.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
LastRowSheet8 = Worksheets("Sheet8").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
LastRowSheet4 = Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

 src4.Unprotect
 dst4.Unprotect

 If src4.FilterMode = True Then
    src4.ShowAllData
End If

 dst4.Cells.ClearFormats
 dst4.Cells.Clear


 'Find content in the "Type of Rack" cells
    j = 3
    For i = 10 To LastRow
        If src4.Cells(i, "CL").Value = "" And src4.Cells(i, "GV").Value = "" Then
        src4.Cells(i, "CL").EntireRow.Copy dst4.Cells(j, 1)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i

src4.Range("A6:GW7").Copy Destination:=dst4.Range("A1:GW2")

'Copy every column EXCEPT the following
dst4.Range("GW1,CM1:GU1, U1:CK1,R1:S1,P1,J1:M1").EntireColumn.Delete

For i = 1 To LastRowSheet4
    For i2 = 1 To LastRowSheet8

    If Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("P" & i).Value = Worksheets("Sheet8").Range("A" & i2).Value Then
        Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("Q" & i).Value = Worksheets("Sheet8").Range("K" & i2).Value
    End If

    Next i2
Next i

dst4.Columns("A:AX").EntireColumn.AutoFit
dst4.Rows("1:500").RowHeight = 15
dst4.Columns("N:O").Interior.Color = vbYellow
dst4.Rows("1:2").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
dst4.Range("B:I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True


 End Sub
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `Match(Sheet4.Cells(i,"Q").Value...`

Comment: Thank you, Scott! Unfortunately it says Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed. Maybe there's another bigger issue in my code...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like the following code:

```
For i = 1 To LastRowSheet4
    For i2 = 1 To LastRowSheet8

    If Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("P" & i).Value = Worksheets("Sheet8").Range("A" & i2).Value Then
        Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("Q" & i).Value = Worksheets("Sheet8").Range("K" & i2).Value
    End If

    Next i2
Next i
```

You will just need to define the upper ends of both sheets (LastRowSheet4 and LastRowSheet8) and this should work.

Comment: I appreciate your quick answer, Pete. Unfortunately I'm getting this: "Run-time error '0': Subscript out of range". Do you have an idea what that means?

Comment: did you define LastRowSheet4 and LastRowSheet8?

Comment: Yep, like this:
LastRowSheet4 = Sheet4.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
LastRowSheet8 = Sheet8.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Comment: you should try it like this: LastRowSheet4 = Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

Comment: And did you dim LastRowSheet4 as anything? It's always hard to guess the error when you can't see the full code.

Comment: I changed both, but nothing worked. I pasted the full code above. thank you so much!

Comment: I'm surprised your solution worked. When I run the code, i get an error that  Set src4 = Sheet2 and Set dst4 = Sheet4 are not defined as worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I solved the problem with recording a macro and modifying it:

```
Sheet4.Cells(3, 17).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=INDEX('TS-48 Matrix'!C[-7],MATCH('Missing Both'!RC[-1],'TS-48 Matrix'!C[-16],0))"
Range("Q3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("Q3:Q" & lastRowSheet4)
```